# Electrostatic potential of a charge distribution with a uniform electric field

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential

I'm trying to solve an exercise in which I have certain charge a dielectric distribution that is useful to solve in spherical coordinates. In particular, it's a spherical dielectric of radius $a$ within a spherical shell of charge $\sigma(\theta) = \sigma_0 \cos (\theta)$ with radius $b>a$. That's not a problem for me since I know how to solve for that. The problem is that I also have a uniform electric field $\mathbf{E}=E_0 \hat{\mathbf{z}}$ and I'm supposed to find the electrostatic potential **everywhere**. I'm not sure how to deal with this electric field since now at infinity the electrostatic potential is no longer zero.

Comment: If it's a uniform electric field, then doesn't that mean it is the same everywhere where the field exists?

Comment: Yes, but added to this field there's the charge distribution. What the uniform field tells you that there's a non-zero field at infinity.